# 3 text box Math in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I am NewBee in Javascript. This is my second week.

Below is the code that has a form with three input fields. 

 The relationship of the fields is:

- the second field is twice the value of the first field
- the third field is the square of the first field

I have managed to do the above but i am not able to do the below :
If a user enters a value in the second or third field, the script should calculate the appropriate value in the other fields. 
Currently the code works well **ONLY** if I enter the value in the first field.

I hope I explained well in other words : how do I enter say 144 in the last textbox and the other 2 textboxes show 12 and 24 respectively. Or If I enter 24 first and first and the third text boxes show 12 and 144.

Thanks
Vipul

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.onload = init;

            function init() {
                var button = document.getElementById("usrButton");
                button.onclick = save;
                onkeyup = doMath;

                function doMath(){
                    var base = document.getElementById("base").value;
                    var baseNumber_timesTwo = document.getElementById("baseNumber_timesTwo").value = (base*2); 
                    var baseNumber_square = document.getElementById("baseNumber_square").value = (base*base) ;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="base" id="base" onkeyup= "doMath()">
            <br><br>
            <input type="text" name="baseNumber_timesTwo" id="baseNumber_timesTwo" onkeyup= doMath()>
            <br><br>
            <input type="text" name="baseNumber_square" id="baseNumber_square" onkeyup= doMath()> <br><br>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello Vipul, are you asking for actual code or for a decent hint/approach towards your problem? The code you provided is a decent start, where exactly is your problem (since you seem to know how this should work in general)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at the code below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        window.onload = init;

        var init = function(){
            var button = document.getElementById("usrButton");
            button.onclick = save;
            onkeyup = doMath;
        }

        var doMathbase = function(){
            console.log('here');
            var base = document.getElementById("base").value;
            var baseNumber_timesTwo = document.getElementById("baseNumber_timesTwo").value = (base*2); 
            var baseNumber_square = document.getElementById("baseNumber_square").value = (base*base) ;
        }
         var doMathBase2Time = function(){
            var baseNumber_timesTwo = document.getElementById("baseNumber_timesTwo").value; 
            var base = document.getElementById("base").value = (baseNumber_timesTwo/2);
            var baseNumber_square = document.getElementById("baseNumber_square").value = (base*base) ;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="base" id="base" onkeyup= "doMathbase()">
        <br><br>
        <input type="text" name="baseNumber_timesTwo" id="baseNumber_timesTwo" onkeyup= "doMathBase2Time()">
        <br><br>
        <input type="text" name="baseNumber_square" id="baseNumber_square" onkeyup= "doMathBaseSquare()">
        <br><br>
    </form>
</body>
```

You need to bind another function to the second and third field. I did it to the second. Now if you entered a number in the second field it return the 'base' number and the square of the base.

Try do it for the third :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Johnny. I am trying to make it work. Appreciate your answer and time.

Answer (score 0):

This should fit your needs:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qbrzbpy3/48/)

```js
//declaring those earlier saves you to get those by ID every
//time you call "doMath()" or something else

var base = document.getElementById("base");
var baseNumber_timesTwo = document.getElementById("baseNumber_timesTwo"); 
var baseNumber_square = document.getElementById("baseNumber_square");

function clearUp() {
    base.value = ""; 
    baseNumber_timesTwo.value = "";
    baseNumber_square.value = "";
}

function doMath() {
    //check which of the fields was filled
    if(baseNumber_timesTwo.value){
        base.value = baseNumber_timesTwo.value / 2;
    }
    if(baseNumber_square.value){
        base.value = Math.sqrt(baseNumber_square.value);
    }
    
    //fill other fields according to that
    baseNumber_timesTwo.value = (base.value*2); 
    baseNumber_square.value = (base.value*base.value) ;
    
}
```

As you see: There is no need to write more than one arithmetic function if you make sure that only one value is given at the time of evaluation (this is achieved by the cleanUp()
method)
However there are still some flaws in this solution! Since you are a js beginner I would suggest you to read the code and think about possible solutions for those problems as a little exercise :-)
- You cannot enter a 2 (or more) digit number in any field, why not? What do you have to change in order to allow such numbers as input?
- Why is it better (in this case!) to set the values to " "  instead of '0' in the cleanUp function? Why does the code break when you try using '0' instead of "" ?
- Why does doMath() only check for values in the last two field (baseNumber_timesTwo and baseNumber_square) while ignoring the 'base' field?

Greetings, Tim

Comment: Thank You Tim. Appreciate it. I am going through the code Hopefully I can understand your exercise to attempt them :)